# Python: Get rid of u's from the keys list generated from json

Tags: python, json

My input file xyz is:

```
{
"one": "a", 
"three": "b", 
"eight": {
    "twelve": "c", 
    "twenty": "d"
         }
}
```

My program is:

```
import json
my_data = json.loads(open("xyz").read())


print my_data
def get_keys(dl, keys_list):
    if isinstance(dl, dict):
        keys_list += dl.keys()
        map(lambda x: get_keys(x, keys_list), dl.values())
    elif isinstance(dl, list):
        map(lambda x: get_keys(x, keys_list), dl)
keys_list = []

get_keys(my_data, keys_list)

print keys_list
```

Output I'm getting is:

```
{u'eight': {u'twelve': u'c', u'twenty': u'd'}, u'three': u'b', u'one': u'a'}
[u'eight', u'three', u'one', u'twelve', u'twenty']
```

output I want is:

```
keys_list = [eight, three, one, twelve, twenty]
```

I have to use this keys_list further in program so I want it in this format only

Please look into it.

Comment: Those U's aren't actually part of the string. They signify that the string is a unicode string. If you're worried that you'll try to do `my_key[0]` later and get back "u", you don't have to worry about that - the first character is still what you'd expect it to tbe.

Comment: There is **no need** to "get rid" of these.

Comment: Thanks guys, I am not getting those removed now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I have to use this keys_list further in program so I want it in this format only

What exactly will you be doing with it? It generally doesn't matter if you have a string or a unicode string.

Any way, you can convert these unicodes to strings:

```
keys_list = map(str, keys_list)
# or keys_list = [str(key) for key in keys_list]
```

Comment: Thanks bro...  I need to save {u'eight': {u'twelve': u'c', u'twenty': u'd'}, u'three': u'b', u'one': u'a'}  this in some external file as a json or  dictionary format, how to do it, I mean output file should not have those u's , I dont want that overhead.